# Classical inheritance vs prototypal inheritance in Javascript VS Objective-C VS Swift

Tags: javascript, objective-c, swift, oop

I'm an iOS developer who learn Javascript now.
My previous experience is related to Objective-C and Swift.

However prototype inheritance in JS got be confused when I try to compare it with inheritance model in Objective-C and Swift.
I've read a lot of articles on this topic but still have some questions.
My questions are:

*1) Does the answer on the inheritance type model significantly depend on the specific language at all?*

2) In Javascript as I understand there is no such concept as *Class* and even ES6 Class acts as a wrapper for **Prototype**.
Prototype doesn't work as a *blueprint* as in classical inheritance model.

*Where is the **border** between **Class** and **Prototype** in the context of **blue-print***?

3) A lot of articles I've read highlighted Javascript flexibility to change prototypes chains on the fly.

However in Objective-C using objc runtime we can slightly achieve something like replacing superclass by *isa swizzling*. Or add methods/properties "on the fly" with objc.runtime.
And Class serves as an object itself in Objective-C. It has an isa pointer to superclass, can respond to messages, etc.

*Can we state that Objective-C (or other languages) can **mimic** prototype inheritance with some techniques?*

Or in the context of this question **Class** should be treaded as an abstract term, rather than its implementation details?

*4 Can we achieve smth like prototype inheritance in Swift? 
Does it matter in the context of static/dynamic typed languages?*

Comment: It is preferred if you post separate questions instead of combining multiple questions into one. That way, questions are more likely to get complete answers, and those searching for one of your questions are more likely to find what they're looking for.

Comment: 1) - what? 2) what is **blue-print**? 3) Can you state that? Yes. is it correct? 4) Does it matter to you?